# Chrome App Poor Performance

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am developing a Chrome App which is based on the same code as the normal web based version. It's a web-audio app so quite performance critical for timing purposes.

I have noticed whilst holding down the mouse button within the app and wiggling it around, performance drops significantly, enough to mess up the timing. This issue does not occur in the ordinary browser based version which is running the same code.

I have recorded the activity with the Chrome developer tools and the only thing I can spot that does not happen with the browser based version is a function call to updateAppWindowProperties - which is a built in Chrome App function.

I have attached a screenshot of the dev tools recording where you can see 3 big spikes in the activity, these are the bits where I am holding down the mouse button and moving it around.

Anyone know what the cause of this could be, is it something to do with the Chrome App checking the window size?

[image: Chrome App Performance]

Comment: Ok, I think I have figured this out. It seems to have been fixed by reducing the number of css classes. I had a LOT of classes that were used only for jquery selectors, I changed them to data attribs and that seems to have fixed the performance issues.

Comment: so if that works, make an answer out of it and accept it as a solution. Could be helpful for other people, otherwise the question will be autoremoved in a few months-year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been fixed by reducing the number of css classes. I had a LOT of classes that were used only for jquery selectors, I changed them to data attribs and that seems to have fixed the performance issues.